# Mono p/invoke giving 'undefined symbol __dso_handle'

Tags: mono, pinvoke, ld, dllnotfoundexception

I added the .so to LDConfig following [this](http://www.mono-project.com/DllNotFoundException) article. Still getting the following. You can get the source for the code [here](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux). Here is the log from the startup of the binary.

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono 39dll-4-linux.exe
Mono: gc took 20 usecs
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x1bd58e0] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll[0x1bd4c10]: 2
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x1bd58e0] added to domain 39dll-4-linux.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/nick/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '39dll-4-linux.exe'.
Mono: Image addref 39dll-4-linux[0x1c520f0] -> /home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe[0x1bd3980]: 3
Mono: Assembly 39dll-4-linux[0x1c520f0] added to domain 39dll-4-linux.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe.so: /home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '39dll-4-linux.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '39dll-4-linux.exe'.
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe.so: /home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/39dll-4-linux.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref 39dll-4-linux[0x1c520f0] -> mscorlib[0x1bd58e0]: 2
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so: undefined symbol: __dso_handle'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libWinsockLib.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so: undefined symbol: __dso_handle'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so: undefined symbol: __dso_handle'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libWinsockLib.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: '/home/nick/Projects/39dll-4-linux/39dll-4-linux/bin/Debug/libWinsockLib.so: undefined symbol: __dso_handle'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libWinsockLib'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libWinsockLib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.

Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: libWinsockLib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) dll4linux.Net:dllInit ()
  at dll4linux.SockLib.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at dll4linux.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: libWinsockLib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) dll4linux.Net:dllInit ()
  at dll4linux.SockLib.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at dll4linux.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I am completely stumped. Any ideas as to whats going wrong?

FYI, I am invoking the following C# code:

```
[DllImport("libWinsockLib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "dllInit")]
public static extern Double dllInit();
```

Finally, I used the following build commands to build the 39dll-4-linux project:

Executed for each .cpp file:

```
g++ -fPIC -c -o obj/<filename>.o <filename>.cpp
```

Then I executed:

```
ld -G obj/*.o -o 39dll4linux.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I figured it out. Turns out, ld is not a good way to package and link a shared library.

Instead of the ld command, i used:

```
g++ -shared obj/*.o -o 39dll-4-linux.so
```

It works like a charm!